# Apache rewrite module interprets POST request data as `false`

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, post

I'm new to apache, and based on some tutorials I build an `.htaccess` file to rewrite the urls.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^print/([\s\S]*[.pdf]*)$ phantom.php [NC]
```

From a `form` I send a `POST` request to the `phantom.php` file, with three fields:

1. `document` - an html string
2. `title` - a string
3. `formatted` - a boolean value

With the help of apache I build user friendly urls, like this one: http://example.com/print/document.pdf

However the `phantom.php` file that receives the POST request gets the boolean as `false`, no mater how I set it.

How can I get the real value of the data and not the `false` value?

Comment: Does it work without the rewrite rules in place? Where is your form markup and your  PHP code?

Comment: Change form action to `phantom.php` and see if that works